# How to translate the Nation name into the current culture?

Tags: c#

I've a List of `Nations` that's scraped from the web, this is returned in english. I saved each `Nation` inside a list like this:

```
List<Nation> Nations { get; set; } = new List<Nation>();
```

where `Nation` have this implementation:

```
public Nation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

the property `Name` contains the name of the `Nation` *in English*, so essentially I'll get something similar to:

```
England
Italy
France
...
```

I'm looking for a way to translate the name of each item of the list `Nations` in the current culture, so suppose that the current software language is italian:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it");
```

how can I translate all the nations in italian language?

I doesn't found any method in `.NET` framework that allow this in a simple way like:

```
//Get the current language of the app
var language = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

//Iterate through all items of the list and change the language 
foreach(var nation in nations)
{
    nation.Name = GetTranslatedName(nation.Name);
}
```

any suggestions? Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: _"how can I translate all the nations in italian language?"_ - by obtaining a dictionary. The .NET FCL doesn't do translations like that.

Comment: @CodeCaster I had imagined it, thanks anyway for confirm

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no native support in .NET for this.
I'd suggest to use [this third-party API](https://restcountries.eu/#api-endpoints-name):

For instance: https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/Ukraine

Answer (score 0):

You can try Google Translate:

Pass language pair as `en|it`

```
public string GoogleTranslateText(string textToTranslate, string languagePair)
{
    string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", textToTranslate, languagePair);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    string translatedText = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    translatedText = translatedText.Substring(translatedText.IndexOf("<span title=\"") + "<span title=\"".Length);
    translatedText = translatedText.Substring(translatedText.IndexOf(">") + 1);
    translatedText = translatedText.Substring(0, translatedText.IndexOf("</span>"));
    return translatedText.Trim();
}
```